# Let (a_n) and (b_n) converge. Prove that $\lim_{n → ∞} (a_n b_n) = \lim_{n → ∞} (a_n) \lim_{n → ∞} (b_n)$

Tags: analysis

My only idea to prove it was to compare $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n$ to $L_1 $ and $\lim_{n \to\infty} b_n$ to $L_2 $.
And then I tried to convert it to $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_nb_n$ in this way:

right side = $\lim_{n \to\infty} a_n * \lim_{n \to\infty} b_n = L_1*L_2 = L_1L_2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_nb_n$ = left side

However, I am not convinced that my reasoning is correct.
I would ask for a correction if anything in my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: You haven't proven anything. All you've done is rewrite $\lim a_n \lim b_n = L_1L_2$. You need to show $\lim a_nb_n = L_1L_2$.

Comment: By writing the fourth $=$ sign in your argument, you are assuming what you want to prove. How do you even know if $a_nb_n$ has a limit, and if it does, how do you know that it must be $L_1L_2$? You need an $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument.

Comment: Hint: Use $\lvert a_nb_n -ab \rvert = \lvert a_nb_n-ab-ab_n+ab_n\rvert \leq \lvert b_n\rvert \lvert a_n-a\rvert + \lvert a\rvert \lvert b_n - b \rvert $

Comment: You can have a look at this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2423796/399263